# Jquery Countdown Timer only loads once on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Hi all trying to troubleshoot some Jquery that was written before i got here ( i am no javascript master) I am basically trying to replicate the function on another place on the page with the same HTMl elements (different id's) the javascript is as follows:

```
enter code here<script type="text/javascript">
    // set minutes
var mins = 5;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
if (document.getElementById) {
minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
// if less than a minute remaining
if (seconds < 59) {
seconds.value = secs;
} else {
minutes.value = getminutes();
seconds.value = getseconds();
}
secs--;
setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
}
function getminutes() {
// minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
// take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
<!-- /Countdown start -->
```

My goal is to use this same function to create a second timer display the HTML for the timer that is working is

```
<div class="timer-order timer" id="" >
                Expires In <input id="minutes" class="timer-order-text"> minutes <input id="seconds" class="timer-text22 timer-order-text"> seconds.
                <script>countdown();</script>
            </div>
```

this is probably a novice question but can i duplicate the function replacing the ids with new ids and make this work? what is the proper way to duplicate the same function when it uses .getelementbyID Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I translated the code into more of a "resuable" component

http://jsbin.com/gijanera/1/edit?html,js,output

You should probably be loading it when the DOM is ready so in your code you'd have the Timer function referenced externally or within the code. Then when the DOM is loaded ( not sure if you are using jquery or not ) you'd put this in between script tags...

```
<script>

    var initMinutes = 5,
        timer = new Timer( "insertMinutesId", "insertSecondsId", initMinutes );

    timer.start();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() only executes once. You want to use setInterval() instead.

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp for more information.

Comment: For more accurate timing (with a loose definition of 'accurate'), recalling `setTimeout` with a recalculated delay is better.  `setInterval` can drift with system load and no way to recalibrate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use this,added comments so that it can be easy understood, in `5*60000`, 5 denotes number of minutes. Here is **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wotohage/1/edit?html,js,output)**

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date().getTime() +5*60000;

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

    if(days== 0 && hours== 0 && minutes==0 && seconds==0)
stopTimer(); 

}, 1000);

//to stop timer
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```